# Laragon and Laravel - sendmail not working

Tags: php, windows, laravel, sendmail, laragon

I use Windows 10, Laragon and Laravel Framework.

And I setup the default Auth by calling `php artisan make:auth`

The problem is when I try to use the Forgot Password component, the 'sendmail' does not work.
After I click `Send Password Reset Link`, nothing happened. And the `Password Reset Link` does not sent to the Laragon's `Mail Catcher`.

This is the configuration inside `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_SENDMAIL="C:\laragon\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -bs"
```

And this is inside `config/mail.php`

```
'sendmail' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'),
```

Comment: I added a more detailed question on this, because this is a possible Laravel bug, were I need some feedback from you guys, testing this on a other machine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212826/laravel-sending-mail-not-working-tinker-hanging-when-trying-to-use-sendmail-v

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I was using custom username and password I got from my Cpanel hosting email account to setup laravel mail. It did not go through via the sendmail config or smtp config.

Reading up the doc i noticed laravel does extend the swift mailer class. I made my twick thus.

```
$user = User::find(1);
      $text = (new WelcomeEmail($user))->render();

        // Create the Transport
        $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport(env('MAIL_HOST'), 25))
          ->setUsername(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))
          ->setPassword(env('MAIL_PASSWORD'))
        ;

        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport RFCValidation
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

        // Create a message
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Happy to Have You Onboard'))
          ->setFrom([env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')])
          ->setTo(['miracle@yahoo.com'])
          ->setBody($text , 'text/html')
          ;
          $message->setReadReceiptTo(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'));



        // Send the message
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Now the

> "new WelcomeEmail"

is a Laravel mailable that bundles the view for the mail. You can brilliantly create your own mail class out of this above code to make your code tiny and extendable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to edit config/mail.php - making use of .env file should be doing the job.

In file 'config/mail.php' you can find the code, how the sendmail path is being structured by default:

```
'sendmail' => [
    'transport' => 'sendmail',
    'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'),
],
```

Possibly in case of different Laravel versions, it could also just be a typo, so try with changed name MAIL_SENDMAIL to MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH.

But to be honest, I was also not able to get sendmail working with Laragon's executable. If someone had success, please share your solution.

Comment: Also have this issue, page is not rendering and in endless processing state... A solution will be really appreciated.