# Laravel - Sending mail not working, tinker hanging when trying to use sendmail via Laragon on Windows

Tags: laravel, sendmail, laragon

In facts I found this question: [Laragon and Laravel - sendmail not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805879/laragon-and-laravel-sendmail-not-working) ... but I decided to post a detailed new question, to get a response, that this issue is possibly a laravel bug... Thank you.

- OS: Windows 10
- Laravel Version: 8.75
- PHP Version: 7.4.27
- Database Driver & Version: sqlite

#### Description:

I trying around getting sendmail (Laragon) to work, but without luck.
File '.env' got adjusted to use sendmail instead of smtp on a fresh laravel project.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

- created new laravel project
  `laravel new test`
- adjusted .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH='C:\LARAGON\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -bs'
```

- run command:
  `php artisan tinker`
- run tinker command:
  `Mail::raw('Hello World!', function($msg) {$msg->to('mail@example.com')->subject('Test Email'); });`

After running the tinker command, the cmd is hanging...

Also tried different options on the sendmail flags:

- sendmail.exe -t -i    <<< tinker hangs
- sendmail.exe -t       <<< tinker hangs
- sendmail.exe -bs     <<< tinker hangs

I can see that the sendmail.exe is running (in task manager), but seems not be able to finish (waited several minutes).
Cancelation (CTRL-c) will close the tinker session and the sendmail.exe ist terminated.

With other php built-in mail function Laragon is working fine and also successfully catching the sent mails in the mail folder.

I always tried to clear configuration cache after every change of the .env file.
`php artisan config:clear`

Sending mail via php works fine as expected with the following code:

```
<html>
   
   <head>
      <title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      
      <?php
         $to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
         $subject = "This is subject";
         
         $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
         $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
         
         $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
         $header .= "Cc:afgh@somedomain.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
         
         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
         
         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
      ?>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone try this out on other Windows machines?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this happens when there is an authentication issue with sendmail.

Make sure you have setup sendmail with your gmail credentials, as suggested by the [Laragon Documentation](https://laragon.org/docs/mail-sender.html)

[image: Laragon Send Mail Settings]

Additionally, gmail disables "less secure apps" by default. Make sure your account has less secure apps enabled here too (or even better, use an Application Specific Password): https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I don't want to use gmail. I just want to catch the mail locally via Laragon mail catch folder... no need of sending mail to google. Why is it working with the PHP without using gmail?!

Answer (score 0):

output `phpinfo()` and check if you have the exact location define on `sendmail_path`

you also need to define it inside `config/mail.php` like

```
'sendmail' => [
    'transport' => 'sendmail',
    'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
],
```

or pull the value from your `.env` file `MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH`

```
'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH')
```

Additionally, you may try using `smtp` driver with localhost info in your `.env` file, you can see these details in `phpinfo()` as well

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

try creating a route to send the email or dump the error

```
Route::get('/test-mail', function () {
    try {
        $send = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::mailer('sendmail')->send([], [], function ($message)  {
            $message
                ->to('to@email.com')
                ->from('from@email.com', 'Test')
                ->subject( 'My Subject' )
                ->setBody('Test Content', 'text/html');
        });
        dd($send);
    } catch (\Exception $e )  {
        throw new \Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }
});
```

Comment: When I change back to smtp with localhost I got an error: Swift_TransportException
Process could not be started [The system cannot find the specified path. ]  (config cache cleared)

Comment: update your sendmail path to the correct path specified on your ```phpinfo()```

Comment: path is correct: https://i.postimg.cc/c424b4Zn/2022-02-22-13-41-03-PHP-7-4-23-phpinfo.png

Comment: I mean what about the path on ```sendmail``` inside ```config/mail.php``` ? the error thrown is saying something about incorrect path

Comment: also try using forward slashes on your path instead of backward

Comment: also no luck, tinker is always hanging. also changed to a local separate installation folder of sendmail that I can tweak the config. I was using localhost and port 2525... only hanging.

Comment: post your ```app/config/mail.php``` file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RwS3SRMu - I'm setting all via .env file and so this is the untouched generated version. There shown is the default path to sendmail. When I use this path, then I get an error, that executable is not being found (because of windows and linux paths are different) with a expected message.

Comment: I've edited my answer, try creating a route to send email instead from tinker and check if any exception is captured

Comment: I added your code in my project. When I try to send the mail the browser is now in loading state... (likely endless) - sadly no error output. Feeling like a timeout...

Comment: ... still loading state. It seems that this request will not come to end (sendmail.exe is still running)

Comment: After killing sendmail.exe it got this error in laravel:
"Exception: fwrite(): write of 261 bytes failed with errno=22 Invalid argument"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on windows 11 laragon laravel

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH='C:/laragon/bin/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t'
```

Make sure to get exact sendmail path from laragon by going to

laragon(Right click in laragon) > php > Mail Catcher > Get sendmail_path.

I don't have reputation to post comment.